# How to iterate over files in web application

Tags: spring-boot, file, war

How I can iterate over files in spring boot web application ?

[image: here]

When I try something like this:

```
            // resolve dir with responses
            File resourceDir = new File(new ClassPathResource("responses/files").getURI());

            // read response files
            for (File responseFile : resourceDir.listFiles()) {
                // do something
            }
```

I got exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
        at java.base/java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418)
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view this should work:

```
File fileResource = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:responses/files");
for(File file : fileResource.listFiles()) {
    System.out.println(file.getName());
    System.out.println(file.getPath());
}
```